# When is objects assigned to instance variables created

Tags: java

Consider a simple code:

```
public class Graph {

    private final List<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    private final int vertexCount;
    private int edgeCount;

    public Graph(int vertexCount) {
        this.vertexCount = vertexCount; 
    }
}
```

My question is when is adjList object created, in other words when is memory allocated to adjList?

Is it after constructor call (unlikely) ?

Before (coz a class can be static with private constructor) ?

If before precisely when considering the code is constructed like:

```
Graph g = new Graph(10);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to understand that `adjList` is not an object. It's a variable - a field. The space for the `adjList` variable is assigned as pretty much the *first* thing that happens when an instance of `Graph` is created... before any constructor calls even start.

Next, the VM walks up the inheritance hierarchy, evaluating any constructor arguments which are needed until it gets up to the `Object` class, and then it executes the body of the constructor there... then the stack pops to execute the constructor bodies of subclasses. So if you have:

```
class Foo extends Object
class Bar extends Foo
```

then the constructor body for `Object` gets executed first, then `Foo`, then `Bar`.

It's only when the constructor body executes that the *instance initializers* are executed. That's when this call occurs:

```
new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()
```

That creates another object, and then the initializer assigns a *reference* to the new object to the `adjList` variable. It's important to understand that the value of `adjList` isn't an object - it's a reference. So there are now two objects (one `Graph` and one `ArrayList`) and a reference within the `Graph` object to the `ArrayList` object. (In practice the `ArrayList` will also have a reference to an array.)

Answer (score 3):

[jls-12.5  :  Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5)

> Whenever a new class instance is created, memory space is allocated for it with room for all the instance variables declared in the class type and all the instance variables declared in each superclass of the class type, including all the instance variables that may be hidden (§8.3).

Answer (score 0):

```
   private final List<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    private final int vertexCount;
    private int edgeCount;

    public Graph(int vertexCount) {
        this.vertexCount = vertexCount; 
    }
```

becomes:

```
   private final List<ArrayList<Integer>> adjList;
    private final int vertexCount;
    private int edgeCount;

    public Graph(int vertexCount) {
        adjList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        edgeCount = 0;
        this.vertexCount = vertexCount; 

    }
```

The default memory is allocated right after `new` is called and after that the constructor is called by JVM. From there, all instance variables are instantiated in the constructor. And explicit definitions are moved inside the contructor body by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is when is adjList object created, in other words when is
>   memory allocated to adjList?

Being an instance variable, it will be created when instance is created.

> Is it after constructor call (unlikely) ?

It will be created as part of the constructor call because constructor will make sure to create the object in the memory as per the instance variables.

> Before (coz a class can be static with private constructor) ?

No, only static variables are created before constructor call. Static variables are created when the class is loaded.

Comment: No, not after the constructor call - as *part* of the constructor call.

Comment: @JonSkeet Right Jon, as part of constructor, thanks! corrected.